# CKeditor not loading in chrome

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I try to implement the CKeditor wysiwig in my laravel project.
My config looks like:

```
<html>
 <head>
     <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  {!! Form::label('text', 'Bericht') !!}
  //Generates textarea with class ckeditorArea
  {!! Form::textarea('text', null, ['class' => 'form-control ckeditorArea'])!!}
 </body>

  <script src="/plugin/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/functions.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
  <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script>
      // Replace the <textarea class="ckeditorArea"> with a CKEditor
      // instance, using default configuration.
      CKEDITOR.replaceClass = 'ckeditorArea';
  </script>
</html>
```

The wysiwig loads in Firefox and Internet Explorer but wont load in chrome.

I cleared cache, did a hard refresh and everything I could imagine that would help.

***EDIT***
Im developing on localhost with xampp.

It seems to be **jquerys** fault, Ive added jquery cdn it worked for a second than stopped working. Im getting really desperate.

Using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost works fine, why isn't it working with localhost is the final question than.